# Mimic Visual Studio IntelliSense filtering behavior in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there an IntelliSense setting in Visual Studio Code to "filter" by Property, Method, Extension Method, or Template, similar to the behavior found in Visual Studio?

Visual Studio 2015:

[image: Visual Studio 2015]

Visual Studio Code (notice the `List` methods and `LINQ` extension methods are mixed together):

[image: Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, we have the **IntelliSense filtering** from VS 2017 RC version, not the VS 2015, please check this: [Productivity in Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/28/productivity-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/)

I have checked the VS Code IntelliSense and its settings, there is no such feature for it. After research, I found some other community members already reported this user voice to the VS Code Product Team, please have a look at this: [Add action(and ultimately a shortcut) to narrow auto suggestions by suggestion type #18639](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18639)

Now the VS Code Product Team have not added any update yet, you can try to add a comment to know the current progress of this requested feature, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Btw, I've confirmed (on my machine) that IntelliSense filtering is also available in VS 2012.

Comment: @Bᴜᴅɪ maybe an extension?